# Serialise IMessage Protobuf to json C#

Tags: c#, json, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a proto file like below:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package _abbbd3832ad747a0a1b0cd1b3c6d6579;

enum Allocator {
  // This needs to be here as a zero value.
  DO_NOT_REMOVE = 0;
  VALUE = 1;
};

enum StandardEventCodes {
  // Signal: N/A
  POWER_UP = 0;

  // Signal: N/A
  WAKE_UP = 1;

  // Signal: N/A
  POWER_OR_WAKE_UP = 2;
};

enum StandardFilterCodes {
  // Signal: The current profile.
  IS_CURRENT_PROFILE = 0;

  // Signal: The restricted mode
  // 0 - unrestricted
  // 1 - restricted
  // 2 - transport
  // 3 - invalid
  IS_RESTRICTED_MODE = 1;
};

enum StandardActionCodes {
  // Signal: The profile to apply.
  APPLY_PROFILE = 0;
};

message Config {
  message Profile {
    enum State {
      ACTIVE = 0;
      SLEEP = 1;
      HIBERNATE = 2;
    };

    // The profile's state.
    State state = 1;

    // What will wake the device up (input, adc_threshold, cell, etc).
    uint32 wakeup_mask = 2;

    // How long to wait before applying this profile in seconds.
    uint32 delay_s = 3;
  };

  repeated Profile profiles = 1;
};
```

I have managed to generate a cs from protoc compiler. However, is it possible to generically generate a json file.

```
var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                            where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMessage))
                                     && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                            select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IMessage;

foreach (var instance in instances)
{
    string json = instance.ToString();  // doesnot work
    Console.WriteLine(instance.GetType().GetNestedTypes().ToString()); // doesnot work
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instances)
```

Json usually work without annotating the classes. But some features, like serializing derived objects may require annotating the classes with attributes. This model, with annotated classes is common in .net. I would consider using [Protobuf.Net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net) since this follows the same model, and makes it fairly easy to use the same classes for both protobuf and json serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small library that should help you address your issue. It adds support for Google.Protobuf types to System.Text.Json.

You can get it from nuget --> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Protobuf.System.Text.Json/

It's pretty easy to use. All you need to do is to enable protobuf support on `JsonSerializerOptions`.

```
var msg = new SimpleMessage
{
    DoubleProperty = 2.5d
};

var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
jsonSerializerOptions.AddProtobufSupport();
var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(msg, jsonSerializerOptions);
```

Comment: this would require init a object from a proto generated class. is it possible to convert to json without creating an object.

Comment: What would like to have in this JSON document?

Comment: @Gauravsa maybe you're looking for sth like https://github.com/chrusty/protoc-gen-jsonschema to generate JSON-Schema from protos directly?